# Asm bytecode queries

Tags: java, bytecode, instrumentation, bytecode-manipulation, java-bytecode-asm

Hey all,
I am trying to use the ASM bytecode Tree Api to do static analysis for a class.
I guess I have a pretty basic question. In a method say foobar(), I have a list of instructions within foobar (InsnList which has a List). Now I want to check if at instruction number 10, whether a function "barfoo(String args)" is being invoked.

Also seperatly, I need to verify whether a particular instruction is a conditional.

Thanks and Regards,
SJ

Note: I can already read a class and reach the particular method I am interested in and iterate through each intruction of that method.

Solved (see: Greg's comments):

```
    AbstractInsnNode s = ...
    if(s.getType()==AbstractInsnNode.METHOD_INSN){
        MethodInsnNode methodInvocationNode = (MethodInsnNode) s;
        if(methodInvocationNode.name.equals("barfoo"))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks Chris.... dint knw we are suppsd to do that.... doing nw

Comment: Do you know what the individual JVM instructions mean? Just trying to figure out where you're starting from here.

Comment: Yes I do.... Ive gone through the ASM manual....

Comment: Then what's the question? Given the instruction at offset 10, you should know how to determine whether the bytecode there is invoking a specific function. Similarly, given a specific instruction it should be trivial to determine whether it's a conditional or not.

Comment: greg, Im glad its trivial. Using asm for the first time. Suppose ive an AbstractInsnNode instruction (the current instruction), how do I perform the check for invocation of a function or conditional? Do i compare the opcodes?

Comment: Yes, it looks like `AbstractInsnNode` has a `getOpcode()` method, which returns the bytecode of that instruction. Look up that instruction in the JVM reference, and see whether it's a conditional instruction (for example).

Comment: I guess I could do that for the conditional. But if I need to check an invocation of a userdefined method, its opcode would be? I can see something like "invokespecial : call method in a specific class" in the reference.

Comment: That's right, invokespecial is one of the bytecodes that can invoke a method (there are a few more). It looks like you'll have to call `getType()` on your instruction node, and if the type is `METHOD_INSN` then you can cast to a [`MethodInsnNode`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm30/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/tree/MethodInsnNode.html). From there, look at `.name` to see the method name.

Comment: I added an answer to your question with the above info, to give you something you can accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the ASM javadoc, it looks like you'll have to call `getType()` on your instruction node, and if the type is `METHOD_INSN` then you can cast to a [`MethodInsnNode`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm30/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/tree/MethodInsnNode.html). From there, look at `.name` to see the method name.

Answer (score 0):

Simple - once you've determined that you've invoked `foobar`, start incrementing a counter on each instruction you visit.  On the tenth invocation, perform your check for the invocation of `barfoo`.

Comment: He doesn't need to run the code for the visitors to visit the class/method/instructions.